# Call JBoss Webservice from another JBoss instance

Tags: web-services, jboss, wsdl, jax-ws

I was trying to call Webservice on JBoss(A) from another JBoss server(B).

I can invoke Webservice deployed on JBoss(A) nicely from the Webservice Client which I created with source code made by "wsimport".

But when I deploy this client onto JBoss(B) and called from Servlet, the client threw  exception.

Root of the exception is

`Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named       {http://searchrequest}HotelSearchWebService in wsdl     http://xxxxxx:8080/schedule_jsf/HotelSearchWebService?wsdl`

I double checked urls and names, nothing is wrong.(I mean same names and addresses with local client which works fine)

I was thinking simply deploy Websevice Client on Server and it will work happy forever.

But it seems like some specific configuration needed.

Does someone have any idea?
Or if somebody knows any example source code on the web.

I will be happy with any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

Somehow my pojo parameters that created by jaxb had empty element name.
When I added annotation attribute, it worked fine.

Now everything is OK, my server is working beautiful.

Thanks for your visit and have a nice day, everyone.

Comment: Could you show what did you change?